# React - Add login/logout button on the navbar

Tags: reactjs

code and preview [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vc551s)

I am new to React and I have set up a very basic front-end session.

The user has to sign in on that page (https://react-vc551s.stackblitz.io/signin) in order to get access to https://react-vc551s.stackblitz.io/dashboard. He is also able to log out on that page (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vc551s). If the user is logged out and try to access the `/dashboard` page, he is going to be redirected to the `/signin` page.

What I have hard time to do is to move the login / logout button to the `navbar`. My `Navbar` is a separate component and I don't know how to do it.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to show button based on user auth. state then, do this-
Save user auth status in local storage or cookie. Initialize the status in state variable(true or false), then in your navbar component add a condition inside your return statement.

```
{isAuthenticated?  <button>Logout</button>:<button>Login</button>}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use `useContext` to make my life easier to manage the auth state. The `useContext` is a global state which can be accessed from everywhere by calling the context. Learn more in [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)